# Add columns to a data frame by for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, matrix

I have a matrix `data` and a `list`. I would like to find matches between each vector in my list with row names of my matrix, calculate their mean and add those values in data frame `df` with new coumn of data frame having the same name as the names of each vector in the list.
I have done it manually, but I am wondering how can I do it in a `for loop` manner with more efficient codes.

```
data <- matrix(runif(75, 5.0, 10), nrow = 15, ncol = 5)
rownames(data) <- paste0("GENE",1:15)

colnames(data) <- paste0("COL",1:5)
list <- list(n = c("GENE1","GENE2","GENE3"), s = c("GENE4", "GENE5","GENE6","GENE7"),b = c("GENE8","GENE10", "GENE12", "GENE15"))

df <- data.frame(row.names = colnames(data))
df$n <- matrixStats::rowMeans2(t(data[intersect(row.names(data),list$n),]))
df$s <- matrixStats::rowMeans2(t(data[intersect(row.names(data),list$s),]))
df$b <- matrixStats::rowMeans2(t(data[intersect(row.names(data),list$b),]))
```

Comment: Use `set.seed` while generating random data, don't name your variable as `list` since it is an internal R function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimise instead of loops try `lapply` in base R, where we subset rows based on `rownames` in each element of list and then take mean of every column using `colMeans`.

```
t(do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) 
                   colMeans(data[rownames(data) %in% x,]))))


#            n        s        b
#COL1 7.242129 7.667626 6.980115
#COL2 7.317233 6.297818 6.186642
#COL3 6.709917 7.061652 7.552923
#COL4 7.773472 6.741069 7.765780
#COL5 7.039789 6.584206 7.569894
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(runif(75, 5.0, 10), nrow = 15, ncol = 5)
rownames(data) <- paste0("GENE",1:15)

colnames(data) <- paste0("COL",1:5)
lst <- list(n=c("GENE1","GENE2","GENE3"), s = c("GENE4", "GENE5","GENE6","GENE7"),
    b = c("GENE8","GENE10", "GENE12", "GENE15"))
```

Comment: That was very helpful Ronak! thanks a lot. what dose '%in% x' part do? and where that x is coming from? because when I try this on my real data i get an error ' Error in colMeans(justRMA.batch[row.names(justRMA.batch) %in% x, ]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions '

Comment: @symo I am not sure how your real data is different from the sample data but can you check `t(do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) 
                   colMeans(data[rownames(data) %in% x, ,  drop = FALSE]))))` if this works ?

Comment: FYI, using `matrixStats::colMeans2(data, rows = rownames(data) %in% x)` is more memory efficient than `colMeans(data[rownames(data) %in% x, , drop = FALSE])` since it completely avoids the subsetting and therefore is also faster.